# How does one find and replace text in all open files with LibreOffice?

Tags: text-processing, editors, libreoffice

How does one find and replace text **in all open files** with [LibreOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice)?

Comment: This does not seem to be Unix- or Linux-related.

Answer (score 2):

the only way I can think of is with a script or macro.  I'd probably do it with python, since that's what I'm more familiar with, but there's some useful info on how to do it in OOBasic [here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=83030).